# ShapesRange.Group method fail - VBA for powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to group two objects (rectangle, oval) on a slide
I am getting "run time error -2147467259 (80004005) Shapes.Range : Failed"

In a nutshell, I loop through each slide of the presentation, discarding the placeholder objects by filtering out `Shape.type <> msoPlaceholder`
Remainder shapes are collected in an array

```vb
Dim ShpCollection as Variant
Dim i as integer, k as integer

For each Slide in PPT
i = 0
Redim ShpCollection(i)
    For each Shape in Slide
        if Shape.Type <> msoPlaceholder then
            Redim Preserve ShpCollection(i)
            ShpCollection(i) = Shape.Name
            i = i + 1
        end if
    Next Shape
    For k = 1 to 5000
        DoEvents 'to allow shapes to be 
    next k
    MSPowPnt.Presentations("PPTName.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes.Range(ShpCollection).Group  
    'MSPowPnt is a variable representing late binding of Powerpoint application
Next Slide
```

The error occurs in line -

```vb
MSPowPnt.Presentations("PPTName.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes.Range(ShpCollection).Group*
```

Weirdly, the below works -

```vb
MSPowPnt.Presentations("PPTName.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Array(ShpCollection(0),ShpCollection(1) ).Group*
```

I am just not able to understand why referring to array of elements works but array variable does not?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

See above for representative code

Comment: Are you sure you want to group shapes from Slides 2 (or 3 or 4) with Shapes on Slide 1?

Comment: Sorry that its not clear from my code snip. The code fails even for the first slide, error as described above.

Comment: Even though you're declaring the `ShpCollection` and using it as an array, try explicitly declaring it as an array: `Dim ShpCollection() as Variant` and see if that works

Comment: Hey Peter, that worked !

Comment: I cannot believe that I split so many hairs over a pair of braces after the variable name!
Below works : 

Dim ShpCollection() as Variant

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your code successfully merges shapes on slide 1 because the `ShpCollection` only holds shapes on the 1st slide.

```
MSPowPnt.Presentations("PPTName.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes.Range(ShpCollection).Group
```

However, after that, `ShpCollection` starts collecting shapes from other slides as well. This means the next run of the `Group` method will fail because it includes shapes from different slides.

- To fix this issue, you should reset the `ShpCollection` at the beginning of the `For` loop. This will ensure that it only holds shapes from the current slide you are processing, and the grouping operation will work as expected.

```vb
Sub GroupAllShapes()
    Dim ShpCollection() As Variant
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        i = 0
        ReDim ShpCollection(i)
        For Each Shape In oSlide.Shapes
            If Shape.Type <> msoPlaceholder Then
                ReDim Preserve ShpCollection(i)
                ShpCollection(i) = Shape.Name
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Shape
        oSlide.Shapes.Range(ShpCollection).Group
     Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that it is not clear from my code snip. The code fails even for the first slide, error as described above
I moved the bit "i = 0 Redim ShpCollection(i)" inside the loop over each slide in Slides collection, still getting the same error.
As I mentioned, the Shapes.Range(Array(ShpCollection(0),ShpCollection(1))).Group does work but Shapes.Range(ShpCollection).Group does not, even for 1st slide.

Comment: Please test my code w/o change first, then adapt it for your project. `MSPowPnt.Presentations("PPTName.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes...` qualifies `Shapes` with `Slides(1)`. btw, `For each Slide in PPT` and `For each Shape in Slide` in your snippet don't work.

Comment: I tested your code and it still gave me the same error as mentioned above. After explicitly declaring ShpCollection as Array, it worked fine. See Peter's suggestion above

Comment: Both `Dim ShpCollection As Variant` and `Dim ShpCollection() As Variant` works well on my pc.